# How can I get the Form to just be on the page

Tags: list, javascript, web-part, form

I want to make it so that when you come to my page you see the form and fill it out not extra steps. I already created the list and generated a New, Display and Edit form in designer. What web part should I be using to do this? Im using 2013

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Page Viewer Web Part. Display the form and copy the URL. Append "IsDlg=1" to the end of the URL or Query String.

```
http://YourServer/sites/yourSite/Tasks%201/NewForm.aspx?IsDlg=1
```

Modify the Source= parameter to point to the page you want the users to visit after completing the form.

```
http://YourServer/sites/yourSite/Tasks%201/NewForm.aspx?Source=http://SomeOtherPageUrl&IsDlg=1
```